# MVC3: Updated value does not reflect in text box after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, postback

I am showing a collection of data on my page. I am showing label and Textbox for each row.

Below is the sample code from my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
   @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Persons.Count; index++ )
   {
      @Model.Persons[index].Name
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Persons[index].Amount)
   }
}
```

In the Post Action, I am update Amount (say increasing by 5).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Persons(PersonList presenter)
    {

        for (int index = 0; index < presenter.Persons.Count; index++)
        {
            presenter.Persons[index].Amount += 5;
        }
        return View(presenter);
    }
```

This updated amount is not reflected on the page.
However if I use below code then it is shown properly, like

```
@Model.Persons[index].Amount
```

Or

```
<input type="text" id=@("Persons_" + index + "__Amount") name="Persons[@index].Amount " value="@Model.Persons[index].Amount" ></input>
```

I would like to the reason for such behaviour that why is it happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted values will override the viewmodel values. I've had a workaround for this before using...

```
ModelState["Field"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("NewValue", "Field", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I guess in your case (and I'm not entirely sure what your object is) something along the lines of

```
PersonCollection persons = (PersonCollection)ModelState["Persons"].Value.RawValue;
persons[index].Amount += 5;
ModelState["Persons"].Value = new ValueProviderResult(persons, "Persons", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 5):

Before updating the values, just add ModelState.Clear(), update your collection and return it.